# How To Manipulate String From Input Value On Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input element `<input id="mystring" type="text"></input>`.

The `id` will be like this:

```
mystring = "myid,myid01"
```

When I open a page I want to add a page value to `mystring` like below:

```
mystring = "myid,myid01,page1"
```

If I go to Page2, Page3 then go back to Page1. The value of `mystring` will be like below. Suppose Page1 not added twice:

```
mystring = "myname,myid,page1,page2,page3"
```

I would also like to delete a value on `mystring` like I delete Page2. Then the value of `mystring` will be:

```
mystring = "myname,myid,page1,page3"
```

I tried this script but it didn't work:

```
function changestringvalue() {
    var filters = $("#mystring").val();
    var newFilter = 'test,';
    if (-1 !== (idx = jQuery.inArray(newFilter, filters))) {
        // remove
        filters.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        // add
        filters.push(newFilter);
    }
    alert($("#mystring").val());
}
```

Comment: Would it work to use a js object instead of appending to mystring?

Comment: Hello @mhatch, I am not sure regarding append on js, but what I am looking for I can manipulate on mystring@html input as I already describe above. I try looking script on google where match on my requirement but not found yet..

Comment: `var filters = $('#mystring').val().split(',');` now filters is an array. Later, `$('#mystring').val(filters.join(','));` to push the array back to your input.